# Extract strings before a regex in BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I am new to regex. I am trying to extract the website name from the long URL like below.

http://connect.themediatrust.com/d/?a=19481782541

I am trying to get everything before ".com" part.

```sql
SELECT
  customer_id,
  COALESCE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(referrer_uri, r'([^(.+?)".com"])'),referrer_uri) AS referrer_uri
FROM
  [zz_marketing_analytics.visit_from_zumobi]
WHERE
  referrer_uri="http://connect.themediatrust.com/d/?a=19481782541";
```

I am getting only "h" as refer URI. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: See [SO search results for `REGEXP_EXTRACT` used with Big Query](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-bigquery%5D+REGEXP_EXTRACT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to get everything before ".com" part.

Try below to **start with**

```
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(referrer_uri, r'(.*).com') AS referrer_uri,
  DOMAIN(referrer_uri), 
  HOST(referrer_uri)
FROM (SELECT "http://connect.themediatrust.com/d/?a=19481782541" AS referrer_uri)
```

Comment: Did not realize there is a host function; very helpful :)